# Mocked class function being called instead of only being mocked

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I am mocking a class in spock and just want to check whether the methods inside the method being tested are getting called or not , I don't want internal methods to run.

```
class CalculationManager{
         void processRequest(){
         System.out.print("In process Request method")       }
    }
class CodeProcessor{
          void processMessage(Request request){
          CalculationManager calculationManager = new CalculationManager(request)
          calculationManager.processRequest(request)
  }
}

class Request{
int id
}   

def "process code test"(){
        given:
            CodeProcessor codeProcessor =  new CodeProcessor()
            Request request = new Request()
            request.setId(10)
            CalculationManager calculationManager = Mock(CalculationManager)
        when:
            codeProcessor.processMessage(request)
        then:
            1 * calculationManager.processRequest()
    }
```

In above case i need to check only whether encodeMessage is being called or not. But when i run the above code it runs code inside encodeMessage() also. This is not expected behavious. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong here

Comment: Please don't double-post here and on http://forum.spockframework.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works perfectly fine, it fails with:

```
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 1, Time: 86
Test Failure: process code test(Test)
Too few invocations for:

1 * codeProcessor.encodeMessage(request)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * codeProcessor.processMessage(Request@20b56ae3)
```

Code:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
   def "process code test"(){
        given:
            CodeProcessor codeProcessor =  Mock(CodeProcessor)
            Request request = new Request()
            request.setId(10)
        when:
            codeProcessor.processMessage(request)
        then:
            1 * codeProcessor.encodeMessage(request)
    }
}

class CodeProcessor {
   void processMessage(Request request) {
      encodeMessage(request)
   }
   void encodeMessage(Request request){} 
}

class Request {
    int id
}
```

Comment: Hi Opal, I need to find out why its running for me. As I have not copy pasted the code. Will take a look and repost. Meanwhile, I above case Too few invocations for:

1 * codeProcessor.encodeMessage(request)   (0 invocations)   1 invocation is there from inside the processMessage function. But why is it still getting too few invocations when that function should get called perfectly

Comment: Ok, will try to help with reposted question. Just let me know if it's ok or not. Or provide SSCCE that reproduces the problem and is runnable as the example I provided.

Comment: please refer to above comment regarding my doubt with the results of above code

Comment: I guess that we have different result for the provided code. Could You please provide full example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I have updated the code. Expected: "In process Request method" should not be printed but the case should be successful as the method is being called. Actual: "In process Request method" is being printed, showing that calculationManager is not mocked but is being actualy called

Comment: @MeenalGoyal: I'm getting: `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: CalculationManager(Request)`. This is not SSCCE. Please correct it. There's also a problem with `processRequest` method. It takes no arguments and arguments is passed to invocation.

Comment: Well I guess figured it out :) Thanks for helping

Comment: You could even upvote the answer for all the time spent here. You're welcome.

Comment: Well i dnt have permission to upvote. But i would definetely accept it